# Ajuda na formatação de data vinda do banco de dados

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Estou finalizando um sistema de filtragem de dados vindo do Banco de Dados, utilizando BETWEEN, minha dificuldade está em formatar o campo 'date' para timestamp para fazer a filtragem, segue meu código:

```
$where =  "date BETWEEN $start_timestamp AND $end_timestamp";
$this->db->where($where);
$plannings = $this->db->get_where('plannings', array('teacher_id' => 
$teacher_id, 'status' => '1'))->result_array();
foreach ($plannings as $row)
```

As variáveis  $start_timestamp e $start_timestamp, já estão no formato timestamp, tentei do seguinte modo e obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
$where =  "strtotime(date) BETWEEN $start_timestamp AND $end_timestamp";
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui resolver do seguinte modo:

```
$dataInicial = date('Y-d-m', $start_timestamp);
$dataFinal = date('Y-d-m', $end_timestamp);
$where =  "date BETWEEN '$dataInicial' AND '$dataFinal'";
$this->db->where($where);
$plannings = $this->db->get_where('plannings', array('teacher_id' => 
$teacher_id, 'status' => '1'))->result_array();
foreach ($plannings as $row)
```

Daí surgiu outro problema, a data é salva como 'Y-d-m', até aqui tudo bem, porém se o dia e o mês é inferior a 10 (de 01 a 09), ele é salvo sem o zero!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então ele retorna as dos dados corretos com dados de outros meses ou dias, acredito que eu devo criar um replace, como esse abaixo, nas variáveis $dataInicial e $dataInicial;

```
$year . '-' . ($day < 10 ? str_replace('0', '', $day) : $day) . '-' . ($month < 10 ? str_replace('0', '', $month) : $month),
```

Porém, do modo citado acima não funciona!

Comment: `strtotime` só vai funcionar se o formatado da data for `yyyy-dd-mm`

Comment: Está no formato Y-d-m.

Comment: troque o strtotime por UNIX_TIMESTAMP
$where =  "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) BETWEEN $start_timestamp AND $end_timestamp";

Comment: @Leo Nogueira, não deu erro algum, porém não retornou nada também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, se entendi certo, no seu banco o campo `date` está guardando os valores no formato `yyyy-dd-mm`, e além disso, para os meses entre 01 até 09 ele não guarda o zero, e você quer converter isso para timestamp para poder utilizar na sua condição `BETWEEN`, correto?

Bom, primeiro você tem que tratar esse seu campo `date` no select para que ele fique como uma data normal, ou seja, para os meses menores que 10 tem que vir o zero e no formato 'Y-M-D', isso pode ser feito utilizando a função `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%d-%m')
```

Agora o seu campo date vai  se comportar como um campo no formate DATE corretamente.
Para os campos timestamp, agora você pode convertelos para DATE também, assim:

```
from_unixtime($start_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Agora juntando tudo isso, seu código ficaria assim:

```
$where =  "STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%d-%m') between from_unixtime($start_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AND from_unixtime($end_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')";
```

Você pode testar um exemplo neste [site](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/862639/11).

Comment: Show!!! Muito Obrigado. Salvo meu cérebro.